# Projects in AWS Rstudio

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I was wondering if an RStudio server on AWS has any support for executing different projects concurrently. To give some context, I'm interested in being able to execute two while loops continuously (example below) on the same server non-stop. (Until it fails or until I manually stop execution.)

I know that on the desktop version of RStudio this is possible: I can create two projects and use "open project in new session", effectively opening a second instance of RStudio for me to use. I can then, for instance, write

```
while(TRUE) {print(1); Sys.sleep(5);}
```

in both sessions and they will run simultaneously. It's not too much of an issue for me that they need to be able to communicate, i.e. execute using variables extracted from a common global environment, although that might be a plus. Essentially the justification for the while loop is that there is some data to load in (if I were to run it as a cron script, say) and it's not ideal it loads it in each time, so I simply update variables in the global environment as the loop progresses.

However, from what I can tell, the version of RStudio on AWS does not allow for it; there are projects, but you cannot open a new one in a new session and the only way to switch from one project to another seems to require stopping execution in the current project.

I'm open to any other possibilities when it comes to trying to execute two while loops simultaneously on the same server. I'm hoping to exhaust all available possible choices I have before I consider simply getting another server to run the second while loop.

Comment: do you have access to terminal? (assuming it's a linux machine)

Comment: Yes, I do, I have access to Bash.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332104/open-another-terminal-window-with-the-same-ssh-session-as-original-window) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the) work for you? You can run multiple R scripts if you could open up a new terminal..

Comment: I don't think so - I'm not looking to run the scripts from terminal, although I can do something like that using cronR. I'm looking to run the scripts (the while loops) from the browser version of AWS, mainly because it's easier for me to launch / observe / terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run projects concurrently is to do so under different usernames.  You'll need to add additional accounts at the Linux level and then log into them to set the projects going.  If you close the window without logging out they'll keep running (this would be easier with two different browsers with different sets of cookies).